# jstree - tree nodes are recreated after adding a new node or removing an existing one

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

i built a tree with nodes using jstree. the user can choose the color background of the node with a colorpicker in the contextmenu.
Unfortunately i noticed that when a new node is created or another one removed, the tree seems to be recreated. indeed css stuff get lost and things added in `node.data` too.

how can i prevent this?

this is my code:

```
function treeCreation(){
  var core = {
    'check_callback': true,
  };
  var plugins = [
    "contextmenu", "dnd", "search",
    "state", "types", "wholerow"
  ];
  var types = {
    "default": {
      'max_depth': 1
    }
  };
  var contextmenu = {         
    "items": function($node) {
      var tree = $("#tree").jstree(true);
      return {
          "Create": {
              "separator_before": false,
              "separator_after": false,
              "label": "Create",
              "action": function (obj) { 
                  $node = tree.create_node($node);
                  tree.edit($node);
              }
          },
          "Rename": {
              "separator_before": false,
              "separator_after": false,
              "label": "Rename",
              "action": function (obj) { 
                  tree.edit($node);
              }
          },                         
          "Remove": {
              "separator_before": false,
              "separator_after": false,
              "label": "Remove",
              "action": function (obj) { 
                  tree.delete_node($node);
              }
          },
          "Color": {
              "separator_before": false,
              "separator_after": false,
              "label": "Color",
              "action": function (obj) {
                $('#colorpicker').trigger('click');
              }
          }
      };
    }
  };
  var animation = 400;
  $('#tree').jstree({
    "plugins" : plugins, 
    'core': core,
    'animation': animation,
    'types': types,
    'contextmenu': contextmenu
  });   
}
```

i added custom callbacks because i needed to manipulate strings for translating the context-menu. Maybe it depends on that?

Answer (score 0):

This question has been answered in [Github](https://github.com/vakata/jstree/issues/2221).
Basically the way is to create a plugin for jstree which overrides the redraw function.

In my use case, I needed to make each node droppable (jquery-ui) so I've done this:

```js
(function ($, undefined) {
  "use strict";
  $.jstree.defaults.droppable = {};
  $.jstree.plugins.droppable = function (options, parent) {
    this.redraw_node = function(obj, deep, callback, force_draw) {
      var i, j, tmp = null;
      obj = parent.redraw_node.call(this, obj, deep, callback, force_draw);
      if(obj) {
        for(i = 0, j = obj.childNodes.length; i < j; i++) {
          if(obj.childNodes[i] && obj.childNodes[i].className && obj.childNodes[i].className.indexOf("jstree-wholerow") !== -1) {
            tmp = obj.childNodes[i];
            break;
          }
        }
        if(tmp) {
          $(tmp).droppable({
            accept: '.my-css-selector',
            drop: myDropCallback
          });
        }
      }
      return obj;
    };
  };
})(jQuery);
```

Then when creating the jstree, you need to declare your custom plugin:

```js
$('#my-tree').jstree({
  ...
  plugins: ['droppable']
  ...
})
```